# Update old scores without another iteration

Tags: python

I have a list of people that have an old and new score for a video game. The new scores of each player depend on the old scores of the other players. I could easily do this:

```
while not done calculating scores:
    for each player:
        player.new_score = calculate_score(player, players_scores) # this fn uses players' old scores

    for each player:
        player.old_score = player.new_score
```

but I'd rather not have another layer of complexity.
Since the new scores depend on old scores, I DON'T want to update the old scores in the same loop that I update new scores like this:

```
while not done calculating scores:
    for each player:
        player.new_score = calculate_score(player, players_scores) # this fn uses players' old scores
        player.old_score = player.new_score
```

I was wondering if there's a way to execute the same set of instructions as the first block of code without having to iterate through the list of players again.

Comment: I can't think of a way to do it.

Comment: Yeah, this is the straightforward way, and unless there is some bottleneck, I wouldn't mess with it.

Comment: Please provide full sample code.  How does **calculate_score** have access to the scores of the other players?  It doesn't receive a player list, and it's not even a method of the class.

Comment: I have an idea, dependent on the data structures in use.  I'm not sure whether it works the way I want.

Comment: @Prune sorry, I forgot to add the extra parameter for calculate_scores.

Comment: @Prune care to elaborate?

Comment: I'm thinking of a compound assignment, with a list of players on the left and a comprehension or generator on the right.  Perhaps a **map** to apply the update, but I think this would require a **set_score** method for the player class.